# jvisualvm 1.3.5 unable to get heap dump from my remote linux server

Tags: jvisualvm

I want   to get heap dump   of jvm running on   my remote linux prod server .  The new jvisualvm 1.3.5 has the link to get heap dump but when I try to get heap dump I get the error  telling cannot take heap dump from the remote server  for pid...

Please advice me how to get heap dump for my remote jvm.